# Deleting facebook account using API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am writing an app for facebook where users can manage their profile. I am stuck at allowing users to delete their facebook account. One option I have found is use webview with URL as:
https://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account

But what if I want to provide my own custom UI and just send a deletion request to facebook through my android app.

Is it feasible? Couldn't find any relevant API

Comment: For one, the API does not expose such a feature (**or**, I am not aware of it). Your best bet would be do add a `WebView` in an `Activity`, and if a user clicks the _Delete Account_ button, send him to that `Activity` (with the URL to delete). But I have never once seen this feature available in the API. But I wouldn't mind knowing if there is something I have missed. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API which allows a third party app to schedule an account deletion for a Facebook user. 
That functionality is only available via Facebook's help center.